# excluding a column in query results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an entity called EmailLog with entries such as To, From, Subject, Body, etc. in the database.

I would like to exclude Body for efficiency/performance when querying for multiple rows. Not really sure how to accomplish that. I tried using projection (see below), but I get a runtime error saying I can't project onto the Entity type.

```
var results = Repository.Find<EmailLog>().Select(x => new EmailLog
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Subject = x.Subject,
                Recipient = x.Recipient,
                Status = x.Status,
                FirstAttempted = x.FirstAttempted,
                LastAttempted = x.LastAttempted,
                Attempts = x.Attempts
            });
```

This is understandable. I can create a new class without Body and project onto that, but I am applying some pagination to the query and don't want to evaluate the results till after I've applied pagination options. My pagination function looks like this:

```
public static PagedList<T> ApplyPagingAndSorting<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, 
IPaginationOptions paginationOptions)
```

It takes in an enumerable list and applies Skip() and Take() to the list and then enumerates it. So how can I make sure I pass in an IEnumerable list to my function which hasn't been enumerated yet, but the associated query doesn't select Body when finally enumerated or evaluated?

Comment: this should help on that matter https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/09/01/splitting-tables.aspx

Comment: As far as I know the Select() function does not enumerate your result, it is one of the Linq methods using deferred execution. So you should be able to project to a class without Body and pass this to your ApplyPagingAndSorting(), which will then evaluate your result.

Comment: @FlorianHaider, I had tried that before and it gave me an error which was related to something else. But I tried it now and it works. Please submit this as an answer, and I'll be happy to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, calling `Select()` will not enumerate your result, it is one of the Linq methods that defer execution. So if you do a projection to a class without Body, you can still pass the resulting `IEnumerable` to your `ApplyPagingAndSorting()` method.